# Run grunt watch from the startup

Tags: ubuntu, gruntjs, ubuntu-14.04, grunt-contrib-watch

Is there a way to get the:

```
grunt watch
```

command to always run in the background from start-up?

I am using LinuxMint/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mint, I think you can add the command line to your PC's startup as, Menu -> Startup Applications -> Add in the dialog that opens.

OP edit:

Adding this at start-up works:

```
grunt watch --gruntfile=/home/{user}/{dir}/Gruntfile.js
```